# How to create this 'bad photocopy' effect or voluntarily 'thrash-ize' like the pic, but for a text or a photo?

Tags: texture

See how the characters and edges 'bleed' a little bit and the whole grunge xerox vibe of it :))

[image]

Comment: This is a bit broad. Using what: a computer, a camera, both? There are many ways of doing this, with computers and without.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for ideas how to create this effect (photocopied, degraded, Xeroxed, brutal)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118923/looking-for-ideas-how-to-create-this-effect-photocopied-degraded-xeroxed-bru)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have a xerox vibe. In my opinion this is a scan of a laser printed low resolution raster image, or perhaps it's a scan from a badly printed newspaper. The dots are a halftone pattern. Basically it's just a bad print. For the ultimate authenticity you could print a low resolution raster image of some text on a laser printer, and then scan it.

Or, you can simulate it in Photoshop.

1. Create a new document - say about 500 to 600px wide, and type some large bold black text.
2. Do *Image > Mode > Greyscale* choose Flatten, then Discard
3. Do *Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur*, with radius set to 0.5px
4. Do *Image > Mode > Bitmap*. Set the method to Halftone Screen. Click OK.
5. In the dialog that opens, set the frequency to about 20, leave other settings at default.
6. Finally do *Image > Mode > RGB*, and then apply the Gaussian blur again to give this very slightly blurred effect:

[image]

Note: The reason I suggested the Bitmap halftone effect rather than the standard halftone filter was to make it look extra crappy. LOL!

Comment: wow!! thank you so much for ur tutoring :))

Answer (score 1):

- Create an image of the type.
- Save the image as a JPG.
- Open the JPG you just saved (not the original image)..
- Save it as a JPG again...
- ....repeat.

Each save of a JPG will degrade the image. Simply keep saving a jpg as a jpg, open the saved image and resave until you are happy with the degradation.

Comment: so simple yet had to know!! merci :))

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : copy all the layer you have and merge them, then apply a tiny gaussian blur to this new layer and play with the Color Halftone Filter (in Pixelate) parameters (for this kind of effect, put 0 in all the channels). Then put this layer into multiply mode or something.
It should do the trick. Maybe ad a tiny Median (Noise Filter) to this layer also.

(I talk about Photoshop here)

Comment: that's amazing! will do! tyyyy