# Does anyone know what this style/effect is called and how to do it in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

this looks incredibly familiar but can't wrap my head around what it's called and how to do it in Photoshop. so help please :( thank you in advance! credits: artstartingover (tw) & portolafestival (ig)
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not every style has a specific name. The images are perhaps made using the threshold filter in Photoshop - to give a kind of bad photocopy effect.

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much. Have a nice day!

Comment: you can probably get some ideas here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118923/looking-for-ideas-how-to-create-this-effect-photocopied-degraded-xeroxed-bru